# Wordpress - Convert url query string to permalink

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks

I'm workin on a plugin and I need some help.

Basically, I list some companies on the website and if you click on a company name, you go to the company details page.

I'm not using post types. I have created a custom table into the database.

On the listing page, I have a link that looks like this:

```
    <a href="http://www.website.com/companies/details/?companyname=<?php echo $value->company_name; ?>">Read more</a>

    $value->company_name // I take this from the database
```

Everything works just fine, except the details page URL.

Now I get something like this:

```
    http://www.website.com/companies/details/?companyname=My%20New%20Company
```

I use $_GET['companyname'] on the details page and I list the related  company details, from the database.

But, I would like the URL to look like this:

```
    http://www.website.com/companies/details/my-new-company
```

And still be able to get the company name from the URL and retrieve the details from the database.

I hope you can help.

Thank you.

Regards,
AG

Answer (score 0):

Add a new column named **slug** in the table and remove spaces of that title.

```
 $string = "my new company";
    $string = strtolower($string);
    $string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\s-]/", "", $string);
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $string);
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", $string);
    echo  $string;
```

Output: my-new-company

OR 
You can follow this link

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_title/

Comment: Hi, thank you for your solution. I used the sanitize_title. Since no longer send a query in URL, I guess I have to parse the URL on the details page and extract only the slug. $_GET['companyname'] won't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I am using sanitize_title now and added a new column into the database table, called slug.

Now the links on the companies listing pahe look like this:

```
    http://www.website.com/companies/details/?companyname=my-new-company
```

Better than

```
    http://www.website.com/companies/details/?companyname=My%20New%20Company
```

But, if I create the links without a query, I get a 404 page. That is actually normal since those pages don't actually exist.

```
    http://www.website.com/companies/details/my-new-company/
```

The slug was a good idea but how can I make such URLs work?

Once these kind of URLs work, I can parse the URL, extract the company slug and retrieve the related data from the database.

I guess I have somehow to transform the query URL into a permalink and on the details page I have to extract the query from the URL.